# React Native: How can i retrieve a firebase firestore document as an array?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code. How can it be rectified to return an array as an object?

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').get().then((querySnapshot)=>{              
        
          let items = Object.values(querySnapshot);
           this.setState({items});
        console.log(items)

});
```

This is my Database
[image: Firebase Firestore Database Snapshot]

The following appears in the console and isn't friendly to retrieve data from it

```
  Array [
      No {
        "Ad": Ti {
          "$o": true,
          "Co": false,
          "Do": Array [],
          "Fo": Array [],
          "Mo": [Function anonymous],
          "No": null,
          "So": Promise {
            "_40": 0,
            "_55": Promise {
              "_40": 0,
              "_55": null,
.........
```

How can i return this in the console

```
Array [
  Object {
    "imageUrl2": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bnv1-16406.appspot.com/o/images%2FTue%20Sep%2001%202020%2020%3A19%3A39%20GMT%2B0300%20(EAT)?alt=media&token=b9d1a38e-26a2-4d93-af2e-aded4747fff1",
    "shopName": "Buule Mohammed",
    "statuz": "seller",
  },
]
```

Comment: What happend now with code that You have

Comment: @TomaszVizaint I have made some correction to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').get().then((querySnapshot)=>{              
  const objectsArray = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((user) => {
    objectsArray.push(user.data());
  });
  console.log(objectsArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For get data from firestore the method is: 

     const dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').get();
        const user = dbRef.subscribe(o => {
                  o.forEach(u => {
                     console.log(u.data());
                   }              
                })
        });

another method is:
const userRef = this.db.collection('users').valueChanges();
    userRef.subscribe(k => {
      k.forEach(u => {
        console.log(u)
      })
    })

and if you want more data you need create something lik this: 

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getUser().subscribe(u => {
          console.log(u);
        })
      }

and method: 

    getUser = () => {
        return this.db.collection('users').snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(action => action.map(a => {
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User
            return {id, ...data}
          }))
        )
      }
```